# Example of a wot convergent net but not $\sigma -$ weak convergent

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $B(H)$ be the space of bounded linear operators. Define the $\sigma-$ weak topology on it by seminorms $p_{h,k} (x)=|\sum_{n\geq 1}(xh_n,k_n)$ where $h=\{h_n\}\subset H ,~~ k=\{k_n\}\subset H $ and $\sum \|h_n\|^2<\infty , ~~~\sum\|k_n\|^2<\infty$. Also Define weak operator topology on $B(H)$ by seminorms $p_{h,k}(x)=|(xh,k)|$ for $h,k\in H$. I know that $\sigma- $ weak topology is stronger that wot.For see that we have strict inclusion I need an example of a weak operator topology convergent net but not $\sigma-$ weak convergent. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add the definitions you are working with to the question? If I understand the question correctly, such an object doesn't make sense. But I could have misunderstood what you mean.

Comment: @Studenttea : I added the details.

Comment: It's the other way round. Since the $\sigma$-weak topology is strictly finer than the WOT, every $\sigma$-weakly convergent sequence/filter/net is also WOT-convergent, but not the other way round. So you need to find a WOT-convergent filter (or sequence, which would be nicer) that is not $\sigma$-weakly convergent.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Oh, I'm sorry, I made a mistake.

Comment: All WOT-convergent sequences are bounded by the Uniform Boundedness Principle and hence converge $\sigma$-weakly. So you need at least a net.

Comment: @Bryder : I edited it

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a net that is weakly convergent, but not ultraweakly convergent.

I will use the fact that $X_j\to0$ ultraweakly precisely when $\text{Tr}(AX_j)\to0$ for all trace-class operators $A$.

Fix $A$ to be an injective trace-class operator, so that $AP\ne0$ for all projections $P$. For example, you could take $A=\sum_k\frac1{k^2}\,\langle\, \cdot\, e_k,e_k\rangle$ for a given orthonormal basis.

Let $\mathcal F=\{F\subset H:\ F \text{ is a finite-dimensional subspace} \}$, ordered by inclusion. We construct a net of operators indexed by $\mathcal F$ as follows:
$$
T_F=\frac1{\text{Tr}(AP_{F^\perp})}\,P_{F^\perp},
$$
where $P_{F^\perp}$ is the orthogonal projection onto $F^\perp$. 
Then, for any $x\in H$, if we move far enough along the net we will have $x\in F$, so $T_Fx=0$, and then  $T_F\to0$ in the wot topology (and the sot, too!).

But, for any $F$,
$$
\text{Tr}(AT_F)=\frac{\text{Tr}(AP_{F^\perp})}{\text{Tr}(AP_{F^\perp})}=1.
$$
So $\{T_F\}$ does not converge ultraweakly.