# SOT and WOT Dual

Tags: general-topology, von-neumann-algebras

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space and let $e_{n}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$. Let $\phi$ be a linear functional defined on $B(H)$ as follows. $ϕ(A)=\underset{n}∑(\frac{1}{2})^n⟨Ae_{n},e_n⟩$ for A ∈ B(H). Clearly $\phi$ is SOT continuous. Also ϕ is faithful. But we know that no wot continuous linear functional on B(H) is faithful when H is infinite dimensional. In particular $\phi$ is not WOT continuous. This is a contradiction since WOT dual and SOT dual are same. Please help me in finding the error?

Comment: Can you explain to me why $\phi$ is SOT continuous?

Comment: Let $A_{m}$ be a sequence converge in SOT to A. Clearly $A_{n}'$s are uniformly bounded. Now
$$\mid\phi(A_{m}-A)\mid =\mid\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\langle (A_{m}-A)e_{n},e
_{n}\rangle\mid=\mid\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\langle (A_{m}-A)e_{n},e
_{n}\rangle\mid+\mid\sum_{k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\langle (A_{m}-A)e_{n},e
_{n}\rangle\mid.$$

Now the second term in the RHS can be made small by using the uniform bound of $A_{m}$ and the first term can be made small using the SOT convergence of $A_{m}.$

Comment: That works for sequences, but to prove continuity you need an argument that employs nets of operators, where you can't use a uniform bound.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you pls give me an example of a net $A_{\alpha}$ converges to $A$ in sot, but  $\phi(A_{\alpha})$ is not  converging to $\phi(A)$?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The functional $\phi$ is not SOT-continuous. I will use a tweak of the net used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1029301/22857).

Let $\mathcal F=\{F\subset H:\ F \text{ is a finite-dimensional subspace} \}$, ordered by inclusion. We construct a net of operators indexed by $\mathcal F$ as follows: let $B=\sum_n2^{-n}\,\langle \,\cdot\, e_n,e_n\rangle$, so $\phi=\operatorname{Tr}(B\,\cdot\,)$, and let 
$$
T_F=\frac1{\operatorname{Tr}(BP_{F^\perp})}\,P_{F^\perp},
$$where $P_{F^\perp}$ is the orthogonal projection onto $F^\perp$. 
Then, for any $x\in H$, if we move far enough along the net we will have $x\in F$, so $T_Fx=0$, and then  $T_F\to0$ in the sot topology.

On the other hand, 
$$
\phi(T_F)=\frac{\operatorname{Tr}(BP_{F^\perp})}{\operatorname{Tr}(BP_{F^\perp})}=1.
$$